# Fitting data with a function defined as an integral in Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm attempting to fit observational data with a function that is defined as an integral, but I get the error message that "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". Wonder what can be done about this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.special import ellipkinc, ellipeinc

x = []
V = []
Verr = []
Vgas = []
Vdisk = []

with open('NG2403.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        V.append(float(row[1]))
        Verr.append(float(row[2]))
        Vgas.append(float(row[3]))
        Vdisk.append(float(row[4]))
Vdint=interp1d(x,Vdisk)
Vgint=interp1d(x,Vgas)
def ellip_ker(r,R,z):
    num = 4*r*R
    den_plus = (r+R)**2 + z**2
    den_minus = (r-R)**2 + z**2
    arg_plus = num/den_plus
    arg_minus = -num/den_minus
    ellip_ker = (2/r)*(1/np.sqrt(den_minus))*(ellipkinc(np.pi,arg_minus) - (R**2+z**2-r**2)*ellipeinc(np.pi,arg_minus)/den_plus)
    return ellip_ker
def density(r,rho0,c):
    return rho0/(r * (1 + c*r)**2)
def integrand(r1,z1,r,rho0,c,q):
    return r1 * density(np.sqrt(r1**2+(q*z1)**2),rho0,c)* ellip_ker(r, r1, z1)
def V_DM(r,rho0,c,q):
    VDM, err = dblquad(integrand, 0, 100, 0, 100, args = [r,rho0,c,q])
    return np.sqrt(r*VDM)
def V_fit(r,c,rho0,q,ML):
    return np.sqrt((Vgint(r))**2+(ML*Vdint(r))**2+(V_DM(r,rho0,c,q))**2)
popt,pcov=curve_fit(V_fit,x1,V1,bounds=([0,0,0,0],[np.inf,np.inf,1,1]))
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error from? And what are `x1` and `V1` in `curve_fit`? I cant seem to see them defined.